# Is -webkit-column-break-before supported in Android 2.3 WebView?

Tags: android, css, webview

I'm trying to use CSS3 multi-column column layout in my android application using WebView, but want to make sure there is always a break before h1 tags. This rule seems to work in Android 4.0 WebView, but looks like it's ignored in 2.3.3. Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this proprietary CSS property is not supported in WebKit browsers version 533 and below. 
Try to use native CSS3 property instead: `column-break-before`

See also here for more details on how to use this CSS3 property: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/multi-columns/

Comment: column-break-before (without the vendor prefix) doesn't work, and the webkit version for WebView in Android 2.3.4 is 533.1. How do you figure out what features are supported in each webkit build?